# Docker COPY does not cp

Tags: docker

i would like to build my first Docker image, containing Apache Tomcat and a deployed web app. My Dockerfile is really small, based on Tomcat:8.0 image and is supposed to copy a WAR file into Tomcat's appBase.

Build of the image reports success, but the file is nowhere to be found in the container.

Copying from host to the container work w/o issues using "docker cp":

```
[root@edubox dock]# docker cp jdbcdemo_3.war 15dd44bbf992:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# we are extending everything from tomcat:8.0 image ...
FROM tomcat:8.0

MAINTAINER simo

# COPY path-to-your-application-war path-to-webapps-in-docker-tomcat
COPY ./jdbcdemo_3.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8082
```

Image build:

```
root@edubox dock]# docker image build -t simo/jdbcdemo_3 --tag=recent ./
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.24 kB
Step 1/4 : FROM tomcat:8.0
 ---> ef6a7c98d192
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER simo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54d824d7258b
Step 3/4 : COPY ./jdbcdemo_3.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f94330423a93
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 8082
 ---> Running in 74b6dd0364b2
 ---> 9464f11ac18e
Removing intermediate container 74b6dd0364b2
Successfully built 9464f11ac18e
```

I would expect COPY to place the file where specified or an error message because of which this does not work.

Comment: The copy looks like it succeeded to me. Are you sure you aren't bind-mounting over where it copied it to?

Comment: is this file `jdbcdemo_3.war` is in same directory as `dockerfile`

Comment: Why do you think that file isn't inside of your container? Have you checked?

Comment: after you build the image; how do you run the container? what do you expect to see?

Comment: i'm running the container via "docker run <image_ID>". I would expect it to display my index.html when accessing http://localhost:8082/jdbcdemo_3 just like it does when running on my host OS. The reason for no index.html is that the WAR file is not being copied to appBase (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps).

Comment: But you do not publish `8082` port to your host right? If you do not do this you will not be able to access this app form your host on this port.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way,

Keep the "jdbcdemo_3.war" where your Dockerfile exists. And make this change in the Dockerfile.

(remove ./ from your Dockerfile) like,

COPY jdbcdemo_3.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

Comment: hi, i have removed "./" but issue is still in place. The Dockerfile and the war file are present in same directory. And yes I have checked on the container side. The file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

please check the permission side of the file.

you can give full permission and test once. (user:group)

Answer (score 0):

try this:     COPY jdbcdemo_3.war /tmp

In your Dockerfile. And build the image and check in the /tmp directory. If the file copied successfully, give the permission to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ Or copy to /tmp first and then copy from /tmp to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/. Using COPY command in Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Hi and many thanks for offering advice. The issue has been trivial in the end. I have not been examining the correct container.

I did not realize one needs to pick the freshly created image, run the container with this image and only afterwards peek for changes described in the Dockerfile in that container.

I have been looking into parent container which i now understand could not have worked.

Sry for wasting your time ;-)